# Extra space added after list on jQuery reload of div in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am writing a web page which updates a list using jQuery when something is selected. Below the list is a button. The update works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE, a bit of space is added between the list and the button every time it updates. Following is a stripped-down example that does the same thing:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #list {
                padding: 10;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="test">
            <ul>
                <!-- List -->
                <li>
                    <div id="list">
                        <ul>
                            <li>before 1</li>
                            <li>before 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <!-- Button -->
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <button id="button" onClick="reload();">button</button>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function reload() {
        var html = 
            "<ul>" +
                "<li>after 1</li>" +
                "<li>after 2</li>" +
            "</ul>";

        $("div#list").html(html);
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Click the button. In Firefox and Chrome, it stays put. In IE (9), it shifts down a bit (a bit meaning about 10 or 20 pixels. Easily noticeable to the human eye, that is) every time I click it. Can anyone tell me what is causing this?
Thanks.

Comment: For me it looks fine in IE9 (I added a little validator to prove it, I get 46 both before and after): http://jsfiddle.net/qEphF/1/ Problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Interesting. I don't get the problem when I run it in jsfiddle either.

Comment: I also tried it using document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = (etc.) and got the same problem.

Comment: Let's try a different approach then, I update my answer with another solution that may work differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
Seems like the problem is related to IE padding calculating rather than your code, since the same happens using js .innerHtml() directly.

I would then suggest removing the padding and adding margins to the ul, since it affect the element you are removing maybe also the margins will be removed this time.

```
#list {
    padding: 0;
}
#list ul {
    margin:10;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qEphF/6/

---

According to jQuery docs

> This method uses the browser's
>   innerHTML property. Some browsers may
>   not generate a DOM that exactly
>   replicates the HTML source provided.

Maybe you should try a different approach. For example

```
$("div#list").empty().append($(html));
```

Comment: Not sure how much that will help, since `$(html)` works just the same way (via innerHTML) with complex html strings such as the one in the question.

Comment: Moving the padding from #list to #list ul fixed the problem (but keep it as padding, not switching to margin)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #list {
            padding: 10;
        }
    </style>
```

Each time you call the reload function, IE adds 10 padding which is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like you end up nesting `#list`s inside of the original `#list`

Comment: Actually, the button moves the same amount whether I specify the padding to be 10, 50, 100, etc. Although it does work fine if I specify the padding to be 0.